# Rounding UP to the nearest 50 cents in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rounding

There are many PHP solutions online to round to the nearest 50 cents, however, I'm interested in rounding **UP** to the nearest 50 cents.  Thus how would one adapt the following code to round UP to the nearest 50 cents?

```
add_filter('australia_post_shipping_rate', 'shipping_round_to_nearest_50cents');

function shipping_round_to_nearest_50cents($price) {
    if(is_int($price)){
        return $price;
    }
    $payprice = round($price * 2, 0)/2;
    return $payprice;
}
```

Comment: Go research how you would "round up" to the next full number ... and simply combine it with what you have here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function that I found in the [ceil PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).  It will return the value of 1.5 if passed 1.26 in this example.

```
if( !function_exists('ceiling') )
{
    function ceiling($number, $significance = 1)
    {
        return ( is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (ceil($number/$significance)*$significance) : false;
    }
}

echo ceiling(1.26, 0.5); // 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do the following:**

```
$price = ceil($price / 0.5) * 0.5;
```

**Example:**

```
26.42 => ceil(26.42 / 0.5) = 53 * 0.5 = 26.50
26.52 => ceil(26.52 / 0.5) = 54 * 0.5 = 27.00
26.00 => ceil(26.00 / 0.5) = 52 * 0.5 = 26.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly there does not appear to be any easy way to do so using PHP's built-in functions. Here is a simple function that will do so:

```php
function roundUp50($n) {
    $whole = (int) floor($n);
    $frac = $n - $whole;
    if( $frac >= 0.5 ) {
        $whole += 1;
        $frac = 0.0;
    } else {
        $frac = 0.5;
    }
    return $whole + $frac;
};
```

**NOTE**: This is not exact. A number like 2.49 will round to 2.5 but 2.499999999999999 will round to 3 (such repeating numbers can be mathmatically proven to equal the following number).

Comment: "such repeating numbers can be mathmatically proven to equal the following number" - how would the code be complete, including corrections to this limitation?

Comment: You are getting into the realm of arbitrary precision which is outside the scope and more complex. If you expect input with more than 2 decimals I recommend using something like `round($number, 2)` prior to passing the number into this function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner:

```
$price = ceil($price + 0.5) > ceil($price) ? ceil($price) : intval($price) + 0.5;
```